# Search string on numbers on Notepad++

Tags: find, notepad++, subtitle, srt, webvtt

I'm trying to do a Find and Replace action on my subtitles timings. I need to add an hour digit to all my timings. SRT files should display **HH:MM:SS:FFF** not **MM:SS:FFF**, as these are for WEBVTT files. I have added an example set of timings below.

This is my original layout 00:08.853 --> 00:11.158

This is the layout i desire 00:00:08.853 --> 00:00:11.158

Notice i have added an extra 00 to the beginning of each timing.

Can anyone help me with what formula I need to use in order to find all 00:00.000 --> 00:00.000 occurrences, barring in mind the exact numbers will change but the layout stays the same.

I've tried the following but the results come up as 0 occurrences:

Find    ??:??.??? --> ??:??.???

Replace 00:??:??.??? --> 00:??:??.???

Comment: I would have just replaced all words with " 00:" with " 00:00". Notice the extra leading space.

Answer (score 1):

Hit Ctrl+H & tick *Regular Expression*

Find: `\b(\d\d:\d\d\.)`

(Find a word boundary, 2 digits, a colon, 2 digits, a period)

Replace with: `00:\1`

Comment: Excellent that has worked perfectly. Thanks for your help